# How to cross compile qt application for different platforms

Tags: qt, qt4, cross-platform, cross-compiling

How can I cross-compile my application on Qt. As for each project

I need two version

1). Which runs on computer on Qvfb & i386 Architecture

2). Which runs on device with Linux Framebuffer & ARM Architecture

I have already compiled Qt for device as well as for Qvfb. I am able to run examples on both platforms, But How can I cross-compile my applications. I would prefer that both output stays in different directories, that means output of i386 stays in output-i386 platform and output of ARM stays in output-ARM directory.

I am using Qt 4.6 for Embedded Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt takes all platform specific details from mkspec file.

Specify mkspec file to qmake to cross compile by using -spec command line argument of qmake.

in mkspec file there are many defines by which you can customize compiling for different platforms like I can use **DESTDIR** to send final output file to particular directory, **OBJECTS_DIR** to send Objects file to particular directory. **MOC_DIR** to send moc generated files to particular dir, **UI_DIR** to uic generated headers and cpp files to particluar directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set `DESTDIR` in your `.pro` file. See [the qmake variable reference](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#destdir). You might also want to adjust the variables `OBJECTS_DIR`, `UI_DIR`, `MOC_DIR` and `RCC_DIR`.

Comment: Definitely adjust the other directories also.  Otherwise, you might try linking objects built for one platform into an executable built for the other.

Answer (score 2):

The end of [this article](http://thelins.se/learnqt/2009/06/testing-your-embedded-linux-setup-qvfb/) shows you how to change qmake in a working directory (you need to 
run `make destclean` first). This other article outlines the basic [Qt for embedded Linux](http://thelins.se/learnqt/2009/06/an-embedded-linux-development-setup/) environment, just to give you the big picture.